# Assign Nothing to a Short variable in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a below line of code like this.

```
Private Sub SomeFunction(ByRef SomeShortVariable As Nullable(Of Short))

    Dim SomeStringVariable As String = "" 'Let's assume it is "", that's how I am getting it in real time code

    SomeShortVariable = IIf(SomeStringVariable = "", Nothing, SomeStringVariable)  'I want to set SomeShortVariable to Nothing but I am getting 0

End Sub
```

The variable `SomeShortVariable` is always sets to `0` even though I want it to be `Nothing`.

I know `Short` by default will set the variable to `0`.

But how can I make it `Nothing`. I am using `.NET 2.0`.

Comment: It's better to not put a string variable directly in a short, you should convert it. For your question, I'm not sure if it was added in 2.0 but you could use Nullable(Of Short), if it's not there then your only option is to have a second variable as a flag.

Comment: Yes it was introduced in 2.0

Comment: Do you mean that this code run inside a sub/function and the variable SomeShortVariable is passed by the calling code as a parameter?

Comment: I suggest you convert your sub to a function and have the nullable as a return value. There's no reason to have it as ByRef in your example.

Comment: @the_lotus I believe that he just posted the relevant part of the function, but otherwise I fully agree. In that case it also should be static (Shared in VB).

Comment: @the_lotus....will try converting to a function

Answer (score 4):

Make `SomeShortVariable` a [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(Of Short) variable.

**EDIT:**

Also your statement should look like this:

```
SomeShortVariable = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeStringVariable), Nothing, New Nullable(Of Short)(Short.Parse(SomeStringVariable)))
```

**SECOND EDIT:**

If you're using Visual Studio 2005 the above won't work, because the [`If`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) operator was only introduced in VS2008. So what you'll have to do is this:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeStringVariable) Then
    SomeShortVariable = Nothing
Else
    SomeShortVariable = Short.Parse(SomeStringVariable)
End If
```

Of course you will want to validate that `SomeStringVariable` is a *numeric* string first. :)

Comment: It would be better to use `If()` generally, to avoid unnecessary expression evaluation. Otherwise +1

Comment: what is happening exactly in your answer?   If `SomeStringVAriable` is empty then assign `Nothing`, isn't that happenin in my code as well. I have edited my question a bit.

Comment: @Neolisk If is not supported in  VB.Net 2.0...IIf works.

Comment: @Neolisk oh yeah, that's what I meant. I guess my years in legacy VB and VBA aren't so far away! :)

Comment: @user2322507: Not sure what VB.NET 2.0 is, if you meant framework version, it is a supported syntax in .NET 2.0 (VS 2010 SP1). It may be language feature you meant. I think [it was added in VS 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx).

Comment: @user2322507 if SomeStringVariable is either Nothing or empty (""), SomeShortVariable will be Nothing. Otherwise it will be set to the string value, parsed as a Short. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @Crono1981 if SomeStringVariable is either Nothing or empty (""), SomeShortVariable will be Nothing. It is not setting to Nothing. Instead it is setting to 0. I want it to be Nothing.

Comment: If you're using 2.0 then most likely you are stuck with Visual Studio 2005, otherwise I can't think of a good reason not to migrate to 3.5. In any case, indeed you might have to use IIf with VS2005, since If operator only was introduced in VS2008.

Comment: @Crono1981: Yeah no problem with that, both would probably work equally well for the purpose of the question. A side note though, this `New Nullable(Of Short)(Short.Parse(SomeStringVariable))` can be shortened to this `Convert.ToInt16(SomeStringVariable)`.

Comment: i tried making SomeShortVariable to Nullable, but still setting to 0.

Comment: Ok just give me a minute. I was pretty sure this would work but maybe my VB is farther than I thought. I'll try it on my end, bear with me. :)

Comment: Meanwhile i will try to be more specific in question. Will edit more to make it more informative.

Comment: Ah, I see it! The IIf function doesn't behave like the new If operator function. Both parts will be evaluated regardless of the boolean operation results. So if you have an empty string there, it will crash with a FormatException. Hold on, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Crono1981: That's what I kinda meant with that comment. Check my answer if you haven't already - should work in any VB or .NET version.

Comment: I edited my answer. The second code segment should work in any VB.NET version.

Comment: @Neolisk yeah I think my brain deliberately chose to ignore that part of the comment. I've been using If for so long now I completely forgot that IIf wasn't behaving in the same way. Good catch!

Comment: This will still throw a FormatException if your input string isn't a number.

Comment: @JimWooley this is why I mentioned that validation of the string was in order. Didn't elaborate on this because that was beyond the question's scope. ;)

Comment: Still need to validate if it works properly. +1 for your inputs though.

Comment: It should work flawlessly now, given of course that the string does represent a valid short value. If you have any issues write them here and I'll try to help the best I can.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your update, well, that's cause it's `Short`, and not `Nullable(Of Short)` in the parameter. Make it nullable of Short and you are done. Although I would refactor to avoid `ByRef`, have a string parameter `SomeStringVariable` and return a `Nullable(Of Short)`. Then things would start to make more sense.

```
Private Shared Function SomeFunction(SomeStringVariable As String) _
                                                            As Nullable(Of Short)
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeStringVariable) Then
    Return Nothing
  Else
    Return Convert.ToInt16(SomeStringVariable)
  End If
End Function
```

**EDIT:** Actually shorthand syntax won't work in this case, for the reasons I outlined in my comment regarding change to `If`. Just don't use shorthand.

Comment: already tried this....if you see my update my Variable is already Nullable. Mebbe I edited while you were jotting this answer.

Comment: @user2322507: The above post has more ideas than that. It is also best practices to consider. I am not exactly sure what you mean with `Sub` and `ByRef`, but my best guess is that you really wanted a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). Now if you code what you wanted, like you wanted, you will get much less issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for the recommendations to use Convert or Parse on cases where the input string could be something other than an empty string but not a number (any user supplied input). It is typically better to use TryParse unless you are absolutely sure someone hasn't passed something in that you aren't expecting. Consider the following:

```
Dim someString = "a"
Dim someShort as new Nullable(Of Short) 
Dim tempShort as Short

Console.WriteLine(someShort)

If Integer.TryParse(someString, tempShort) then
    someShort = tempShort
end if 

console.WriteLine(someShort)

if Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(someString) then
    someShort = Short.Parse(someString) ' Throws FormatException
end if

Console.WriteLine(someShort)
```

Comment: The question was about having a variable that could either be a Short value or a null value.

Comment: +1....looks like I need to Initialise `new Nullable(Of Short)` in the calling function

Comment: @user2322507 where is this 'SomeStringVariable' coming from, exactly? It doesn't seem to be a parameter of your function, so I'm guessing it's a member of the same class?

Comment: @Crono1981, its coming from a function within the current function. No issues with it. It either returns an Integer value like 1,2,3...so on or it returns "" which i want to set to Nothing but unable to do it in .Net 2.0.

Comment: @user2322507 use a Nullable(Short) throughout and don't pass strings at all. VB 8 didn't support the C# shortcut syntax for nullables (Short?) but it does support Nullables. Even with 4.5, you can't set a short to nothing. You can set it to Default but that would be 0 not nothing. If absolutely necessary, you can set it to Short.MinValue and then compare against MinValue to check for no value supplied as a substitute.

Comment: @JimWooley I'm guessing that the string variable reflects user input, but still I agree with you. Something in this design seems wrong. It might be worth reviewing the whole thing.

Comment: I will review and come back again tomorrow. But will definitely post my final work around.